# Operator "belongs to" in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of values which I have named "List1", and I want to sum all values in column B as follows:

The value in cell B5 is added if and only if the value in cell A5 belongs to List1.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've tried using SUMIF, but I haven't managed to use the function match as a criterion there. Something like

> =SUMIF(B:B,A:A,MATCH(A:A,List1))

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A:A,List1,0)),0,1)*B:B)
```

This is an array formula, and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If done correctly, you will see curly braces (`{` and `}`) appear around the formula.

Comment: The second approach wirks perfectly. Though I want the result to be in column B as well, and now it is giving me a circular error problem. How would you write the same formula, but with a range like A10:A50 and B10:B50 (instead of A:A and B:B)? Thanks again.

Comment: Literally just change `A:A` to `A10:A50` and the same for column B - assuming you're using this formula below the end of your data that would stop the circular reference warning.